# Making a contact form that sends an email from any domain

Tags: asp.net, forms, email

How can I make a 'contact us' form that allows the user to send an email to admin from any domain (gmail,hotmail,yahoo,etc). By that I mean any user with any domain on their email can send an email to the admin's email address. Right now the user can only send emails if they have a Gmail account. Please help and provide any solutions and advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net, you can set user email of any domain, but it should be valid. Set user email in From Property of Mail class.

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "Gmail@gmail.com";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString(); 
    //Password of your gmail address
    const string fromPassword = "Password";
     // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
    string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
    body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

**fromAddress could be any valid email address.**

Comment: seems like i can use it only with the "fromAddress" of gmail ids.What if user can send mail from any address may be of gmail,yahoo,hotmail,etc?

Comment: User can send mail from any address may be of gmail,yahoo,hotmail with the "fromAddress".

Comment: Its working when i am using gmail account as "fromaddress".But when i try to use any other account that is of yahoo or hotmail, it gives an error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

Comment: I am using this smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

Comment: Configure SMTP Server in the IIS and use that one in the code. Regarding configuring SMTP server, you can check on the net according to your IIS version.